# Kept getting The Struts dispatcher cannot be found error in Struts2 web app

Tags: java, struts2, dispatcher

i have some problem here, glad if you can help
i have a program with Struts2 that always kept getting this error report

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.
```

i don't know what i should do
according to a forum i should change the filter dispatcher to

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

but it's no good

here is the web xml of my file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

or

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
```

is making an error ?

what i should do ? any help is good

Comment: what jar you have included in the class path.Also can you show struts.xml file.this dispatcher is inside `strut2-core.jar`

Comment: sorry i dont understand our question:(
jar in my program is all of struts2 and hibernate jar
about struts xml i am confused

Comment: ok my first concern was do you have struts2-core.jar in your class path since this dispatcher is inside this jar and as per execption seems container is not able to find this class.Additioaly need information which version of struts2 you are using and need to have a look at your config file

Comment: yes, i have Struts 2.2.3 Core Libraries-Struts2-core-2.2.3.jar
is that the file you ask ?

Comment: what URL you are hitting when this exception is occuring?

Comment: http://localhost:8084/CRUDTEST/index.jsp

Comment: avoid directly accessing jsp files.go through
actions. Especially when you are using Struts tags inside.

Comment: i have struts 2.2.3, i'm using `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`, and everything is working ok

Comment: can u show us your index.jsp header tags?

Comment: umesh: so what should i do ?
Nacho: i already do that, it's not working

Comment: nacho: <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

Comment: Have you included the jar into your project? i mean, not the physical jar, but the reference to the jar file in your project's configuration/properties. Are you using netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: Is web.xml into WEB-INF folder? Also make sure you don't haver two struts2 jar files included in your classpath from different versions

Comment: @Kevinphytagoras you have already configured welcome file in your web.xml so you need not to hit .jsp file directly.just hit the following URL localhost:8084/CRUDTEST. container will itself look for welcome file which in your case is index.jsp

Comment: @Nacho i'm using netbeans, yes i already have

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes, i already do that. It's still not working

Comment: can u place somewhere your project war to check it?

Comment: Do you mean i should upload it somewhere ?

Comment: Just for us to check it, unless your want to paste all your code in here ;D

Comment: @Kevinphytagoras just post the exception coming on console as well the jar you have in your class-path except the hibernate one.posting struts.xml is also good.

Comment: @Nacho sorry for late reply, where should i upload it ?:D

Comment: Your own server, megaupload is an easy one www.megaupload.com, or dropbox account if you have

Comment: i do it in mediafire
here it is http://mediafire.com/?1ddgcj63r8blm5g

Comment: can't do much with the little you put there, i'm trying adapting it to a project... i'll tell you more

Comment: thanks, the main idea of this project is i want to make a CRUD website using Struts2 and Hibernate. i study it from a website, here the link, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/tutorial-struts2-hibernate-example-eclipse.html
I just want to know why i always have this filterdispatcher error.
This is not the first time i encountered this problem while making a project, it make me curious

Comment: @Kevinphytagoras, i just tried both your project and the test package in that tutorial you posted. Both worked for me, which makes me think your problem is more about your java installation, your project imports configuration (maybe you're importing both a built-in library and the struts2 jar), your glassfish project build folder 'cache' (if you're using glassfish), or even your glassfish not refreshing configuration (running another test project). Keep it up

Comment: @Nacho
should i uninstall my netbeans ?
my question is, why some of my project have no problem with my netbeans configuration ?
my friends also encountered the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml the  ending tag is missing. This may be the problem (or)

This Exception may be due to

1. In Web.xml filter not defined (or)
2. The server doesn't look up the web.xml for Filter Dispatcher.

   Just clean the project, clean the server and restart the server. It will work. (or)
3. You may not included the proper jar for struts. Just verify the jar you are using.

Answer (score 1):

According to your problem in web.xml there is no closing tag for `</web-app>.`

However if it is not working properly then, you just copy the struts-blank.war from this

[struts-blank](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/struts/examples/) link

and import to your IDE run the program (some 3 to 4 jsp page is present just run it will work

properly). Struts-blank war file, it includes library file helpful for the struts development

and for this you won't get any error.